# Scraping Webpage with DOMdocument and DOMXpath

Tags: php, web-scraping, domdocument, domxpath

I'm very new to this. I would like to extract a table from a page using PHP and return it's HTML after modifying the HREF values of all anchors.
Here is the table:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CssGraduateE.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <br>
        <table class="main" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <br><span class="MainHeader">Subjects in Faculty -   Electrical Engineering</span><br><br>
                        <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span class="SecondHeader"> Subject Number</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="SecondHeader">Subject   Name</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="SecondHeader">Points</span></td>
                                    <td><span class="SecondHeader">Semesters</span></td>
                                    <td>Subject Site</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="../Subjects/?SUB=46001">46001</a>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td nowrap="">Engineering of Distributed Software Sys</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td><br></td>
                                    <td><a target="_newtab" href="http://www.thislinkisok.com/courses/046001">www</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="../Subjects/?SUB=46002">46002</a>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td nowrap="">Design and Analysis of Algorithms</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>B<br></td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;<br></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Update on :</td>
                    <td>Wednesday ,9 April 2014</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know how to grab the table I want:
$query = $xpath->query('//table[@class="main"]//table[1]');
but how do I loop through all the links that begin with "../xxx" and modify them to something like this: "www.mynewlink.com/xxx" ?
At the end I would like to return the extracted table as HTML. How do I do this with native DOMDocument and DOMXpath?

Thanks All!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$html` is your string with HTML you get from the external website, you can do something like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query('//table[@class="main"]//a[starts-with(@href, "../")]') as $link) {
    $link->setAttribute('href', preg_replace('#^..#', 'http://www.mynewlink.com', $link->getAttribute('href')));
}

$container = new DOMDocument();
$container->appendChild($container->importNode($xpath->query('//table[@class="main"]')->item(0), true));

echo $container->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Why do I need to create a new $container DOMDocument? Can't I just do this: $table = $xpath->query('//table[@class="main"]//table[1]'); return $dom->saveHTML($table->item(0));

Comment: @user3510841 If you don't do that, you'll only get the inner contents of the table, without the `<table class="main">...`, so we need to create a master container that can hold the entire table including its start tags. Please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to the question, if it worked out for you.

Comment: @user3510841 It's right below the big 0 with arrows pointing up and down :)